# How to add a new group in Active Directory using LDAP in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap

I have scenerio to create new groups in Active Directory using LDAP and C#.

Please provide the suggestions

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, I want to create New Group in AD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article on CodeProject is a really good starting point:

[Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)

To create a group, you need to:

- bind to a container where you want to create the group inside of
- create the group and define some properties

Code:

```
public void Create(string ouPath, string name)
{
    if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://CN=" + name + "," + ouPath))
    {
        try
        {
            // bind to the container, e.g. LDAP://cn=Users,dc=...
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ouPath);

            // create group entry
            DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + name, "group");

            // set properties
            group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = name;

            // save group
            group.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine(path + " already exists"); }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, what will the ouPath look like when checking if the group already exists?

Comment: @G-Man: you can either test for the full path (`DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://YourServer/CN=GroupName,OU=SomeOU,dc=Test,dc=com")`) or you can check if the current container's `.Children` contains your group (`entry.Children.Find("CN=GroupName");` - which will return `NULL`, if no entry by that name exists)

Comment: I am using it like such:  if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"] + "/CN=" + groupName + ", " + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Container"])) 
but then I get an error that say username or password is incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: @G-Man: that error would indicate that your default user doesn't have permissions to read the Active Directory

Comment: @marc_s see my post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233359/check-if-active-directory-group-exists-in-current-container-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 9):

Some addition info on setting the Group Scope and Group Type, the enums are:

```
public enum GroupType : uint
{
    GLOBAL       = 0x2,
    DOMAIN_LOCAL = 0x4,
    UNIVERSAL    = 0x8,
    SECURITY     = 0x80000000
}
```

SECURITY ( Shortened from ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED ) is combined with the first 3 enums to give you the 6 possible options, without it a group will be a Distribution group.

The values are set as an int, which with the security flag goes into negatives, so unchecked() needs to be used.
Alternatively you could create an enum for the combined values.

```
GLOBAL       | SECURITY = 0x80000002 = -2147483646
DOMAIN_LOCAL | SECURITY = 0x80000004 = -2147483644
UNIVERSAL    | SECURITY = 0x80000008 = -2147483640
```

The value is stored in the 'groupType' property:

```
var groupType = unchecked((int)(GroupType.UNIVERSAL | GroupType.SECURITY));
group.Properties["groupType"].Value = groupType;
group.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180903(v=vs.80).aspx

I think you might be looking for this part of the code:

```
// Bind to the domain that this user is currently connected to.
DirectoryEntry dom = new DirectoryEntry();

// Find the container (in this case, the Consulting organizational unit) that you 
// wish to add the new group to.
DirectoryEntry ou = dom.Children.Find("OU=Consulting");

// Add the new group Practice Managers.
DirectoryEntry group = ou.Children.Add("CN=Practice Managers", "group");

// Set the samAccountName for the new group.
group.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = "pracmans";

// Commit the new group to the directory.
group.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got through solving this problem for a .NET Core 2.0 app - here is an updated solution for those using .NET Core 2.0+.

This utilizes the NuGet package `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`:

```
try
{
    string adminUsername = "myAdminUser";
    string namingContext = "CN=Test123,DC=MyCompany,DC=com";
    string hostNameAndSSLPort = "192.168.123.123:636";
    string adminuser = $"CN={adminUsername},{namingContext}";
    string adminpass = "password";

    using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(hostNameAndSSLPort))
    {
        LdapSessionOptions options = connection.SessionOptions;
        options.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        options.SecureSocketLayer = true;

        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(adminuser, adminpass);
        connection.Credential = credential;
        connection.Bind();

        string rolesContext = $"CN=Roles,{namingContext}";
        string nameOfNewGroup = "MyGroup";
        string groupDN = $"CN={nameOfNewGroup},{rolesContext}";
        string dirClassType = "group";

        AddRequest addRequest = new AddRequest(groupDN, dirClassType);
        AddResponse addResponse = (AddResponse)connection.SendRequest(addRequest);
        Console.WriteLine($"A {dirClassType} with a dn of\n {groupDN} was added successfully. The server response was {addResponse.ResultCode}");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Also there are a lot of great code examples in [this sample project provided by Microsoft](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/f/12fbae49-1d05-4542-87a2-9c9dfedafc0c/MS_Sample_Pack_For_SDSP.EXE).