# Check if Active Directory Group exists in current container using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to create a new Active Directory Group.

This is my code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container, userName, password);

GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, userName);
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

if (entry.Children.Find("CN=" + groupName) != null) {

}

if (!DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"] + "/CN=" + groupName + "," + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Container"]))
{

     oGroupPrincipal.Description = groupName;
     oGroupPrincipal.GroupScope = (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope), groupScope);
     oGroupPrincipal.IsSecurityGroup = isSecurity;
     oGroupPrincipal.Save(ctx);
}
```

The Part that I am having trouble with is to see if the newly created group exists before creating it. At this stage my code returns that al the groups exists so I am unable to create a group

This is to check if group exists:

```
if (entry.Children.Find("CN=" + groupName) != null) {

}
```

but it gives an exception There is no such object on the server.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us that those config settings hold? What value do you have e.g. in `groupName` ?? And is your group *really* located at the **top of your domain**?? You need to bind to the **container** in which that group is supposed to exist, e.g. something like `LDAP://yourserver/OU=someOU,OU=topLevelOU,dc=test,dc=com` or something. You cannot just bind to the top-level of the domain and then do a `entry.Children.Find()` - this will **not** go through your entire directory recursively!

Comment: this is my app settings:
<add key="ADServerLDAPPath" value="LDAP://dev.uat.local/CN=Users,DC=uat,DC=local"/>
    <add key="Domain" value="UAT.local"/>
    <add key="NETBios" value="UAT"/>
    <add key="Container" value="ou=IKNew,dc=uat,dc=local"/>

Comment: groupName is the name of the new group that I want to create. in this case it is TestGroup2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the (false) assumption that a `entry.Children.Find()` will do a recursive search through your entire directory - it does **not** do that.

So, either you need to bind to the actual container where that group should be located, and then check its immediate children for existence of your group:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourServer/OU=SubOU,OU=TopLevelOU,dc=test,dc=com", userName, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

try
{     
     DirectoryEntry childGroup = entry.Children.Find("CN=TestGroup2");
     // create group here
}
catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException exception)
{
    // handle the "child not found" case here ...
}
```

or then you need to do a **directory search** for your group which works recursively through your entire directory (and thus will be **much slower**, too):

```
// define root directory entry
DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

// setup searcher for subtree and search for groups 
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(domainRoot);
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.SubTree;
ds.Filter = "(&(cn=TestGroup2)(objectCategory=group))";

var results = ds.FindAll();

if(results.Count <= 0)
{
   // group not found -> create
}
```

Comment: I used the search code and that works perfectly but now when I create the group it does not create group in the correct container. What am I missing?

Comment: I figure it out, I have changed my domainRoot as such:
DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain + "/" + container, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

Comment: Sorry to bother again, how can I can the GroupScope and also IsSecurity to the group using it properties?
group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = groupName;

Comment: Thanks, the code snippet for Children.Find was helpful, but when I used it, it throws an exception for non-existent children as opposed to returning null as it appears your code expects.  Here is a reference, please correct me if I'm misunderstanding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39zxbb5w.aspx